# Why isn't my JDBC Statement updating the database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sql-update

I am trying to update records in my  SQL database. In this case, I am trying to update the record by fetching the email id of the user from a `JSP` form.

My code snippet:

```
        int y=0;
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        String st=request.getParameter("name");
        String s=request.getParameter("email");
        String p=request.getParameter("age");
        Connection c=null;
        
        if (st!=null || s!=null || p!=null) {
        if (c==null) {
            try {
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\storage.db");
            
                    Statement PS=c.createStatement();
                    int i=PS.executeUpdate("UPDATE Details SET name="+st+", age="+p+"WHERE email="+s);
                    if (i==0)
                        pw.println("Can't be updated, record isn't available in our database");
                    else
                        pw.println("Updated successfully");
                    PS.close();
                    c.close();
                
                }
            
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    }
```

But strangely, no record gets updated. Also, no errors show up in the console. Why is this happening?  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I tried working with both `PreparedStatement` and `Statement`. Nothing works.

Comment: Is this print in your IDE console `Entries updated successully!` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't even show the `y` counter when I try to print it.

Comment: Then you need to make sure that you can find records when you `SELECT` data

Comment: `age="+p+"WHERE email="`, to me it looks like there will be no space between the age and the word WHERE, something like _age=25WHERE email="_. If that is the case then the solution is to work with a prepared statement to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: You really should not concatenate values into a query string, it is unsafe as it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection (which is basically the problem with `name="+st+"`,it should be surrounded by single quotes), and it makes it easier to make the typo pointed out by Joakim. Please learn about prepared statements and parameterize your statement.